# Editing an empty Array in Python from a zero array using a summation function

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have initially built np.zeros but have no idea how I input the values. As in change the zeros to the values of the function that I have.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: I need to basically build a matrix A. And then fill in each individual i, jth element with the following formula - sum=sum + a x b. So i thought i should initially build the matrix A using zeros. But i do not know how to edit the zeros if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array using `variable = np.zeros(5)` you get an array consisting of 5 times zeros like so:

```
>>> variable
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To access and change each element of an array you could use index of that element. To set first element to 1 you can write

```
variable[0] = 1
```

Then your variable will look like

```
>>> variable
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To create multidimnesional array, use tuple like so

```
>>> s = (2,2)
>>> np.zeros(s)
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

Comment: That's fab help. Therefore if i want to build a 3x3 array i would simply do variable= np.zeros(reshape(3,3)) ? But then how would i go about changing each element in a 3x3?

Comment: You access first the row, then the column - for 2x2 last element would be `variable[1][1] = 1`
See my edited answer

Comment: Thank you for that. Would you also happen to know how i could multiply a matrix A with its transpose? Would that simply be np.dot (A, np.tranpose (A)) ?